# Fiber bundles, non-hyperbolic surfaces and Thurston geometries

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, geometric-topology, fiber-bundles

Let $ M $ be a compact 3-manifold which is the total space of a fiber bundle (with connected nontrivial fiber and base) where neither the base nor the fiber is a hyperbolic surface. Then $ M $ always admits a Thurston geometry.

Here is a proof:

- For circle bundles over a surface $ \Sigma $
  $$
  S^1 \to M \to \Sigma 
  $$
  A closed 3-manifold $ M $ is a Seifert fiber space if and only if it admits one of $ S^3,S^2 \times E^1,E^3,Nil,\tilde{SL_2},H^2 \times E^1 $ geometry (this is Theorem 1 of [https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~mihmar/SeifertGeometry.pdf](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Emihmar/SeifertGeometry.pdf)). A circle bundle is a trivial type of Seifert fiber space (it is exactly the case when the base 2 dimensional orbifold is actually a 2 dimensional manifold). So every circle bundle over a closed surface admits one of the six fibered geometries. Since our base space is non hyperbolic then the total space of the bundle has solvable $ \pi_1 $ so the geometry must in particular be one of $ S^3,S^2 \times E^1,E^3,Nil $.
- For $ T^2 $ bundles over $ S^1 $
  $$
  T^2 \to M \to S^1 
  $$
  we have by this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416611/torus-bundles-and-compact-solvmanifolds that $ M $ must be homeomorphic to a solvmanifold (thus diffeomorphic since we are in dimension 3). Then by this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414531/3-dimensional-solvmanifolds-and-thurston-geometries/416509#416509 we can conclude that $ M $ admits a geometry (specifically one of $ E^3, Nil,Solv $).
- The two $ S^2 $ bundles over the circle
  $$
  S^2 \to M \to S^1 
  $$
  correspond to the trivial bundle and the mapping torus of the antipodal map of $ S^2 $. Both manifolds admit $ S^2 \times E^1 $ geometry.
- The only $ \mathbb{R}P^2 $ bundle over the circle
  $$
  \mathbb{R}P^2 \to M \to S^1 
  $$
  is the trivial bundle and it admits $ S^2 \times E^1 $ geometry. It is Riemannian homogeneous.
- The four Klein bottle bundles over the circle
  $$
  K \to M \to S^1
  $$
  are exactly the four compact flat non-orientable 3-manifolds. They admit $ E^3 $ geometry. Exactly two of them are solvmanifolds see, the other two are not Riemannian homogeneous

So my question is whether this same sort of result holds for non-compact three manifolds. Basically the idea is what if the 2d part of the bundle admits a flat or round metric then can we still conclude that the total space of the bundle admits a Thurston geometry.

-If the base is a line or plane then the bundle is trivial so the total space of the bundle admits either $ E^1 \times S^2 $ or $ E^3 $ geometry depending on the geometry of the fiber.

So one of my questions is **Let $ M $ be the total space of a bundle with fiber a non-hyperbolic surface ( so only interesting ones left are plane or Moebius strip) and base a circle. Then must $ M $ admit geometry?**

And also **Let $ M $ be the total space of a circle bundle over a  non hyperbolic surface (so only interesting one left is Moebius strip), must $ M $ admit a geometry?**

Finally, **Let $ M $ be the total space of a line bundle over a non hyperbolic surface (so interesting bases are sphere, projective plane, torus, Klein bottle, Moebius strip). Must $ M $ admit a geometry?**

Comment: Ian, LSpice's linked duplicate is _your own question, which you answered_.  Why did you post it a second time?

Comment: @JacobManaker Hey sorry I should have provided more links and explanation. The two links are two versions of the same question one with hyperbolic surfaces and one with non-hyperbolic surfaces. The version for hyperbolic surfaces is false very cool answer by Lee Mosher linked by LSpice as you noted. I've been chewing on the version for non-hyperbolic surface (this question) which I eventually answered in the affirmative for the compact case and updated my question.

Comment: The last thing that remains unanswered in my original idea for the question is whether all line bundles over non-hyperbolic surfaces admit geometries and finally whether bundles of noncompact flat surfaces over the circle always admit a geometry. Hopefully I'm not delusional and what I'm saying now makes sense. This questions assumes that the 2d part of the bundle admits a round/ flat metric and asks if the total space of the bundle has a geometry whereas the linked question assumes that the 2d part admits a hyperbolic metric and asks if the total spaces has a geometry. Let me edit to clarify